# How to rotate a SVG symbol based on a formula of column value and literal value (90 degrees) in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, symbology, fields-attributes, cartography, rotate

I have a shapefile that I have stored in GeoServer. I have some SVG symbols that I want to use for each point. I want the SVG symbols to rotate based on the orientation column (attribute value) in the shapefile plus 90 degrees.

I found that

```
<Rotation> 
    <ogc:PropertyName>rotation_column</ogc:PropertyName>
</Rotation>
```

will rotate the symbol by "rotation_column".

I also found that

```
<Rotation> 
   <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
</Rotation>
```

will rotate 90 degrees.

I want to rotate "rotation_column" + 90 degrees. How can I do it?

This is my whole SLD after applying @Andrea Aime 's suggestion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>CallingInPoint</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>CallingInPoint</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>CallingInPoint (L) - trafficFlow = 1</se:Name>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
              <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <PropertyName>trafficFlo</PropertyName>
                <Literal>inbound</Literal>
              </PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/pixel">
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:ExternalGraphic>
                <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="RadioCallingInPoint_2.svg"/>
                <se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
              </se:ExternalGraphic>
              <se:Size>18</se:Size>
                
                <Rotation> 
                    <ogc:Add>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>orientatio</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Add>
                </Rotation>


              
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:LineSymbolizer>
                <se:Stroke>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#C045D1</se:SvgParameter>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-dasharray">12 6</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>                        
            </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>CallingInPoint (L) - trafficFlow = 2</se:Name>
              <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
                  <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <PropertyName>trafficFlo</PropertyName>
                    <Literal>outbound</Literal>
                  </PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/pixel">
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:ExternalGraphic>
                <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="RadioCallingInPoint_3.svg"/>
                <se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
              </se:ExternalGraphic>
              <se:Size>18</se:Size>
                <Rotation> 
                    <ogc:Add>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>orientatio</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Add>
                </Rotation>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:LineSymbolizer>
                <se:Stroke>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#C045D1</se:SvgParameter>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-dasharray">12 6</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>                        
            </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>CallingInPoint (L) - trafficFlow = 3</se:Name>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
              <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <PropertyName>trafficFlo</PropertyName>
                <Literal>one-way</Literal>
              </PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/pixel">
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:ExternalGraphic>
                <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="RadioCallingInPoint_2.svg"/>
                <se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
              </se:ExternalGraphic>
              <se:Size>18</se:Size>
                <Rotation> 
                    <ogc:Add>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>orientatio</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Add>
                </Rotation>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:LineSymbolizer>
                <se:Stroke>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#C045D1</se:SvgParameter>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-dasharray">12 6</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>                        
            </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
         <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>CallingInPoint (L) - trafficFlow = 4</se:Name>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
              <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <PropertyName>trafficFlo</PropertyName>
                <Literal>two-way</Literal>
              </PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/pixel">
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:ExternalGraphic>
                <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="RadioCallingInPoint_4.svg"/>
                <se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
              </se:ExternalGraphic>
              <se:Size>18</se:Size>
                <Rotation> 
                    <ogc:Add>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>orientatio</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Add>
                </Rotation>   
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:LineSymbolizer>
                <se:Stroke>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#C045D1</se:SvgParameter>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-dasharray">12 6</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>                        
            </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

"orientatio" is the column that I want to have the rotation based on it.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
<Rotation> 
    <ogc:Add>
      <ogc:PropertyName>rotation_column</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Add>
</Rotation>
```

Comment: I applied it and now I have an error: 

line 24: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Rotation'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/se":Rotation, "http://www.opengis.net/se":AnchorPoint, "http://www.opengis.net/se":Displacement}' is expected.

My tags start with <se: ... > yours with <ogc: ...> can it be because of it?
even what does that ogc and se mean here?

Comment: Ouch, you're using SLD 1.1 instead of SLD 1.0. Try adding the prefixes to rotation (<se:Rotation>), but my example was meant to be used with SLD 1.0

Comment: The validation error you have now seems due to the order of the elements, the SLD schema dictates a specific order. Looks like you're working inside a PointPlacement? In any case, see the expected order here: https://schemas.opengis.net/se/1.1.0/Symbolizer.xsd

Answer (score 0):

The answer that @Andrea Aime has suggested is correct. In order to fix the error, I added se: before Rotation tag, But I would appreciate if someone can explain what se: means.

```
<se:Rotation> 
    <ogc:Add>
      <ogc:PropertyName>rotation_column</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Add>
</se:Rotation>
```

Comment: It's a prefix commonly used for the ``http://www.opengis.net/se`` namespace, of the "Symbology Encoding" specification, upon which the SLD 1.1 schema is built.